# array gets deleted using sockets c++ eclipse

Tags: c++, arrays, sockets, char, overriding

I'm having a double-project using sockets.
It starts with a class named "UdpClient" that is sending messages to a class named "UdpConnection" and outputs the message it gets back from it. 
problem is, everytime I send back a message, char-array "buffer" or "answers" is overrided, and I have problem with debugging because it uses the 2 projects. I want to ask if someone sees a problem with receiving and sending, I think the rest is fine.

```
class UdpClient {

unsigned int from_len;
int sent_bytes;
struct sockaddr_in from;
int sock;
const char * ip_address = "127.0.0.1";
int port_no;
const char* answer;
struct sockaddr_in sin;
int data_len;
char buffer[4096];
int bytes;
string input;
bool stayHere=true;

UdpClient::UdpClient(int port) {

port_no=port;
sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
do {
    answer=NULL;
    cout<< "please choose"<<endl;
    getline(cin,input);
    answer = input.c_str();
    memset(&sin, 0, sizeof(sin));   
    sin.sin_family = AF_INET;
    sin.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(ip_address);
    sin.sin_port = htons(port_no);
    sendto(sock, answer, data_len, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&sin, sizeof(sin));
    from_len = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
    bytes = recvfrom(sock, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0, (struct sockaddr *) 
    &from, &from_len);
    cout << buffer << endl;

}while(stayHere);
   close(sock);
}
```

my second class in the project, serverUdp:

```
class UdpConnection {

struct sockaddr_in sin;
struct sockaddr_in from;
int sock, bytes;
char buffer[4096];
char answers[4096];
int sentBytes;
int server_port;
std::string returnStr;
char split_char;
unsigned int from_len;
bool stayHere=true;
std::vector<std::string> tokens;
userInterface starting;

UdpConnection::UdpConnection(int port) {

server_port=port;
sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
memset(&sin, 0, sizeof(sin));
sin.sin_family = AF_INET;
sin.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
sin.sin_port= htons(server_port);
bind(sock, (struct sockaddr*)&sin,sizeof(sin));
from_len = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
do {
    memset(&buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer)); //ADDED NOW
    bytes = recvfrom(sock, buffer, sizeof(buffer),0, 
            (struct sockaddr *)&from, &from_len);
    split_char = ' ';           //to split the message
    std::istringstream split(buffer);  
    for (std::string each; std::getline(split, each, split_char); 
        tokens.push_back(each))  {   };
    returnStr=starting.start(tokens);
    tokens.clear();
    strncpy(answers, returnStr.c_str(), sizeof(answers));
    answers[sizeof(answers) - 1] = 0;
    sentBytes=sendto(sock, answers, bytes, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&from, 
    sizeof(from));

 }while(stayHere);
  close(sock);
}
```

userInterface ("starting.start() method) is the class returning a string. inside it there is a switch-case loop where I receive "tokens" and send a string to the screen. I won't add it here because it's very long, and in addition goes to the right switch and TRIES to print the right message.
it works as expected, wishing to print the right messages everytime, but problem is that those messages get overrided by the previous message.
userInterface class code is ' return "successfull" ' for example, and doesn't have a string object return messages.

expected output is:

```
successfull
successful movie
successful adding
```

actual output is:

```
successfull
successful movie
successful addie     //the length of last message, cut ng and put e
```

Does anyone know where the buffer array needs to get cleaned and why it is causing me this trouble everytime?? HELP..

Comment: Maybe you are (mis)using C-style string functions that stop on the first NULL byte encountered (or using `std::string` incorrectly and using string functions that stop on NULL bytes).  If so, you should be using functions that properly utilize the return value of `send` and `recv` to determine the actual number of characters to process.

Comment: do you have an example for such a function?
I don't know how to stop the first NULL

Comment: Look over the code you didn't post.  Make sure that you are not using functions that automatically stop on the first NULL byte.  Also, there is no reason to "clean out an array".  You are returned in your code a value telling you exactly how many bytes were received.  You should be using that value to size your strings, read your data, create your `std::string` objects from ,etc.  For example, `cout << buffer` should really be `cout.write(buffer, len)`, where `len` is the number of bytes received, `std::string x(buffer, len);` instead of `std::string x = buffer;`; etc.

Comment: Also, if you know you want to send `n` bytes, then send `n` bytes.  Don't send `sizeof(buf)` bytes, since `buf` is a character array, and C++ doesn't know how much *actual* data to send.  If the array is 4,096 bytes, and the real string is only 50 bytes, then the parameter you should be using is `50`, not `4096`.  You should be checking your code for these errors (both overestimating and underestimating the size of the data you're processing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the "**UdpClient**" class, while sending data you're not setting the "**data_len**". It should be like below:

```
data_len = strlen(answer);
sendto(sock, answer, data_len, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&sin, sizeof(sin));
```

Also in **UdpConnection** class, instead of using sizeof(answers) you should use **strlen(answers)** because **sizeof(answers)** will always give **4096** (the size of the answers array) whereas **strlen(answers)** will give you the exact size of the string stored in answers.
While sending also you should use **strlen(answers)** instead of **bytes**

```
answers[strlen(answers)] = 0;
sentBytes = sendto(sock, answers, strlen(answers), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&from, sizeof(from));
```

Comment: you're right man, it performs much better now BUT I still haven't solved the array-cleaning problem